# using git pull after ssh in script

Tags: linux, bash, ssh, git

I use public and private key to ssh to a remote server without password. After that, I need to perform "git pull" command. But I don't know how to pass the password into it. Trying the following solution, but it does not work:

```
#!/bin/sh

ssh user@server '

cd /folder

echo "password" | git pull

'
```

Another thing is I don't want to expose the password in the script. Any suggestion? Thanks

Comment: Are you pulling from a SSH remote or a HTTP(S) one?

Comment: from a HTTP(S) one

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could probably use [.netrc](https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/STASH/Permanently+authenticating+with+Git+repositories) file (note: I havent't done this myself). You could either generate `.netrc` dynamically at runtime or have it sit there.

EDIT: As long as your script has access to .netrc, so does the user that runs the script. So if you give the script to someone else and that someone else has access to the private key, it doesn't matter that you don't have the password hard-coded in the script.

Comment: Thanks. It works! But still password vulnerable

Comment: You could supply the password as command line argument, and write out the `.netrc` file at runtime using that password, then remove the file.

Comment: You may also want to remove `.netrc` using some secure removal tool. Can't give you a suggestion off the top of my head, but I'm sure there are a few out there.

Comment: what I really want is not providing the password not only as command line argument, but also in the script file.

Comment: I don't think that can be done. The whole point of using passwords is that you verify that a user knows it. If user doesn't know it, they shouldn't have access. What you are proposing is defeating the purpose of authentication.

Comment: I think it's best to simply create a separate unprivileged account and give users access to it.